# How can we develop e-commerce website in 20 days using Ruby on Rails and making it fully functional from scratch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I have searched about this but getting more confused as I came to know about Shopify, Spree, Solidus etc. Please suggest me the best option to develop it in 20 days and best flexible gems or any ready made gem or plugin. I'm using Rails 5.2 & Ruby 2.5

Comment: https://snipcart.com/blog/rails-ecommerce-tutorial-refinery-cms might be a good start

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spree` gem to build ecommerce application using rails. https://github.com/spree/spree

Answer (score 0):

purchase a bootstrap template, integrate with rails app. then work 24 hours.